# When to timestamps logs from the UI

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, logging, error-logging

I want to use an API to log errors and capture metrics from the UI , should the timestamp come from the UI at the time of the event or should I append the timestamp when the log request comes to the API?

Comment: What are your goals for the use of the timestamp? Basically, if you allow the UI to create the timestamp, then it's possible for it to be forged. If you create the timestamp within the API, then you are in full control of the timestamp, but don't have the opportunity to batch upload log entries from the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend catching and recording both with the UI in local and Utc (`AtLocal` + `AtUtc` + `ProcessedAtUtc`) with client's `AtUtc` being the 'main' one.

One reason for it is that you can upload errors in batches; use queues etc.

There are real bugs caused by `ProcessedAtUtc` being used as `AtUtc`.